# Smallest integer that does NOT divide a given number

Tags: number-theory

`Divisible[n,m]` yields True if `n` is divisible by `m`, and yields False if it is not. My query is what is the fastest way to determine the **smallest integer** that does not divide a given integer `N`?

For instance, the code below  gives all the numbers (up to 20) that are NOT divisible by 3:

```
If[Divisible[#, 3], X, #] & /@ Range[20]

(* {1, 2, X, 4, 5, X, 7, 8, X, 10, 11, X, 13, 14, X, 16, 17, X, 19, 20} *)
```

What I want is the smallest integer  that does NOT divide 20, which is 3 in this case. How do you find this number (other than the obvious 1 and 2)  for general `N`?

Comment: Obviously, for the odd numbers $>1$, $2$ would be the answer. So, just evens then?

Comment: Oops...forgot to mention that 1 & 2 are excluded. Thanks

Comment: Take the minimum of Divisors and subtract 1. If this is not 1 or 2 you're done. Otherwise just use the smallest number in the complement of the Divisors and Range[3, n].

Comment: You'll get a sequence with a bunch of threes, then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for all numbers which are not multiples of $\text{lcm}(1, \dots, 20) = 232792560$:

```
smallest[n_] := LengthWhile[Range[3, 20], Divisible[n, #] &] + 3
```

If you use $50$ instead of $20$, you get $3099044504245996706400$ as the forbidden number, which might be more acceptable to you.

You could compile this to get something which might be faster. `LengthWhile` isn't compiled by default, although I really don't know why - it's one of the most obviously compilable functions there is.

Comment: `Divisible[]` is not compilable either, but at least one can reformulate with `Mod[]`.

Comment: @J.M. yep, I tried that first. I would have thought this would be really low-hanging fruit for WRI.

Comment: nice, +1. Just wondering how to locate those numbers (up to  10^5) which yield the answers 7 & 8.

Comment: @thils Any multiple of $\text{lcm}(1, \dots, 6) = 60$ but not a multiple of 7.

Comment: If I want the numbers that gives 11, I use  Select[Range[10000], smallestl[#] == 11 &].......output=2520, 5040, 7560

Comment: @thils Or you could just select any multiple of `LCM @@ Range[10] == 2520` which is not a multiple of $11$.

Comment: Yes, that is good. Fast.